# Attempting to filter posts using get_terms

Tags: terms

Using get_terms I've created three lists of term links. What currently happens if I click on a term is to see the archive for that term, what I'm attempting to achieve now is when I click a second term I want to see an archive for both terms not just the latest term. Basically creating some level of filtering posts.

My first guess is that I have to set some variable to affect the query, any suggestions on how to go about this? Or is there a better way of achieving this?

```
<h2>Filter By Deployment:</h2>
<?php
$deployments = get_terms( 'deployments', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => 1) );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $deployments as $deployment ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($deployment->slug, 'deployments').'">'.$deployment->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>


<h2>Filter By Category:</h2>
<?php
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => 1) );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($category->slug, 'category').'">'.$category->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>


<h2>Filter By Keyword:</h2>
<?php
$tags = get_terms( 'post_tag', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => 1) );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($tag->slug, 'post_tag').'">'.$tag->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: If you click now you will go to the `tag` archive. You can't be on 2 `tag` archives at once. So the filtering will have have to go to a custom page, possibly with `$_GET` params

Comment: My thought to deal with that was to delete the tag.php & category.php archives so that all would default to archive.php

Comment: That does trigger that behavious but that doesn't fix how you send over your params

Comment: I did exactly this is a recent project. What I did is use a custom page and set the filter params in the url then use $_GET to rerun the query based on those filters. I'll post an answer later if no one else has posted a similar answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried out isotope? I am working on a project that needs a similar function. So far it's the closest I've found that will sort/filter posts.

The link - http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Here's some questions I had about implementing it with wordpress, and was able to do so to certain extent. It can help get you started -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956593/unable-to-make-isotope-filter-sort-posts-in-wp

[Isotope Drop Down Categories Filter Function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76837/isotope-drop-down-categories-filter-function)

Comment: That looks like something I'll have to try, I've been moved off that project until the new year, but I'll be sure to come back and let you know how it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just try your condition like below. 
I think `$query->is_post_type_archive()` will not be working properly. I have not tried that so not sure.
Directly call `is_post_type_archive()` and `is_page()` function.

```
if ( ( is_post_type_archive( 'question' ) || is_page(3001) ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'question' );
    }
```

Comment: Don't just dump code as an answer. Please explain what your code does and why it should work. Please edit your answer